# Two foreign keys reference to same table in symfony2 querybuilder

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

```
    Table1(identity1, a1,b1)
    Table2(identity, foreign(identity1),foreign(identity1))
```

Now when I use this query

```
              $query = $qb->select('a1', ' b1')
                    ->from('table2', 'm1')
                    ->join('ApiMapBundle:tabl1, 'u1', 'WITH', $qb->expr()->orX('m1. foreign(a1) =u1.identity', 'm1. foreign(b1) = u1.identity '))
                    ->andWhere('m1.identity=:tt')
                    ->setParameter('tt', $cn)
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getResult();
```

Now the problem with this query is that sometimes it gives `id` let's tt:5 so it gives me a value like this

```
      Array(                       
        0 => Array(id => 1,  b1=> 8000225), 
        1 => Array(id => 9,  b1 => 8000234)) given).
```

Basically in table the values structure is like this

```
   Table2(Identity=5,foreign1=9,foreign2=1)
```

Any idea that how can I exactly get the given structure? Because in some cases it is fine they give me proper foreign 1 and foreign 2 but in other cases it make it alternative. Any idea?

Comment: from my point of view you'll have to use two joins - one is not enough here

Comment: How can `a1` and `b1` be a foreign key without being an `identifier`? I think this is not possible in Doctrine2...

Comment: sorry it was wrong edited. foreign  reference here identity1..can you check it now..... basic structure is like this

Comment: two join is not possiable bcz it is return a values and here the reference keys point to the same table...